# How to find the percentage similarity between two 3d models using Meshlab Compare?

Tags: compare, meshlab

How one can find the percentage similarity between two models that has been compared using meshlab features?

Comment: In these terms the question is not clear. Please describe better the issue

Comment: I have two models of an object,say model A and B, generated from two different 3d scanners. Taking model A as base I want to find, how different model B is from A.